# Setting height 100% to div causes vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

There are only 3 lines of text in a div in body. The background color was filling only up to those 3 lines of text.

As I wanted the color to fill up 100% vertical of the browser, I just set the CSS `height` properties of html & body to `100%`. But the vertical scrollbar shows up now. How can I hide/remove it?

I tried `overflow:hidden` for html as well as div properties but no luck. Using Firefox.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.logodiv {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #243640;
  height: 40px;
  color: #FF1442;
}

.content {
  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="logodiv">
  ITEMS LIST
</div>
<div class="content">
  line1<br> line2
  <br> line3
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: You currently have the height set to 100% (content) *plus* 40px (logodiv).  That's why you're getting a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. If i give % for logodiv(20),content(80), would that be a good design approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `logodiv` absolutely positioned:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gcduf/

```
.logodiv
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#243640;
    height:40px;
    color:#FF1442;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . It worked. Could you please explain, how it does.

Comment: @Ruby Using `absolute` positioning removes the `.logodiv` element from normal document flow and the `.content` element goes under the `.logodiv`. check the first two lines, you won't see them.

Comment: @Ruby That's correct. If you use a website inspector like Firebug, you'll see how the div's are positioned.

Answer (score 1):

Use `min-height: 100%` instead and add a negative margin to `.content` to shift it up:

```
.logodiv {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.content {
  background-color: gold;
  min-height:100%;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.content:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo #1](http://jsbin.com/olecaj/1/edit)**

**Note:** In order to push down the content of `.content` element, I used `::before` pseudo-element selector, another option could be:

Using `box-sizing: border-box` and `padding-top: 40px` CSS declarations:

```
.content {
  background-color: gold;
  min-height:100%;
  margin-top: -40px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/olecaj/2/edit)**

**PS:** Nowadays, All major modern browsers support [`::before`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) pseudo-element and/or [`box-sizing`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) property. But if you're looking for the traditional way which all browsers support, you can create a `.spacer` division, as the first child of `.content` element and set `height: 40px;` to `.spacer`.

**[JSBin Demo #3](http://jsbin.com/olecaj/3/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

### Use the [**`calc()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) function.

Make this adjustment to your code:

```
.content { height: calc(100% - 40px); }
```

```css
.logodiv {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #243640;
  color: #FF1442;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="logodiv">
  ITEMS LIST
</div>
<div class="content">
  line1<br> line2
  <br> line3
  <br>
</div>
```

---

You've got `.logodiv` with `height: 40px`.

And its sibling `.content` with `height: 100%`.

Add these two together and they overflow the height of their container (`body`). That's the reason for the vertical scrollbar.

With the `calc()` function you can set up mathematical expressions using addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*), and division (/) as component values.